# Switch statement in jQuery click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use a `switch` statement. I think that I have tried everything already. For some reason it just wont work. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $right = $('#right');
    var $animWebs = $('#animWebs');
    var $simpWebs = $('#simpWebs');
    var $contact = $('#contact');

    $('#txt').addClass('txt', 6000);
    $('#nav').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            left: 0
        });
    });
    $('#nav').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            left: -200
        });
    });
    setInterval(grow, '1000');

    function grow() {
        $right.animate({
            height: 390,
            top: 200,
            borderRadius: '3%'
        }, 1000);
        $right.animate({
            width: 440,
            right: 200
        }, 1000);
        $('#txt').animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 2000);
    }
    var qw;
    $('#click1').click(function() {
        qw = 'asd';
    });
    $('#click2').click(function() {
        qw = 'dsa';
    });
    $('#click3').click(function() {
        qw = 'sda';
    });
    switch (qw) {
        case 'asd':
            $('#click1').css({
                "color": "#d40d0d",
                "font-size": "100%",
                "text-shadow": "0px 0px 2px green"
            });
            $('#right').fadeOut(1000);
            $animWebs.animate({
                top: 170,
                left: 300,
                width: 500,
                height: 400,
                backgroundColor: 'white',
                borderRadius: 6
            }, 3000);
            //$(this).removeClass('click1');
            break;


        case 'dsa':
            $('#click2').css({
                "color": "#d40d0d",
                "font-size": "100%",
                "text-shadow": "0px 0px 2px green"
            });
            $('#right').fadeOut(1000);
            $simpWebs.animate({
                top: 170,
                left: 300,
                width: 500,
                height: 400,
                backgroundColor: 'white',
                borderRadius: 6
            }, 3000);
            //$(this).removeClass('click1');
            break;

        case 'sda':
            $('#click3').css({
                "color": "#d40d0d",
                "font-size": "100%",
                "text-shadow": "0px 0px 2px green"
            });
            $('#right').fadeOut(1000);
            $contact.animate({
                top: 170,
                left: 300,
                width: 500,
                height: 100,
                backgroundColor: 'white',
                borderRadius: 6
            }, 3000);
            //$(this).removeClass('click1');
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: You execute the `switch` statement on load of the page, before `qw` is set, so the value is *always* undefined. You need to put that logic inside it's own function, presumably called when one of the required elements is clicked.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I haven't thought of that!!! Thank you!!! That worked!!!! I have spend couple of days solving that! OMG!!